# MongoDb connected to both nodes in a replica set but command lands at the secondary sometimes

Tags: mongodb, admin, mongo-shell, replicaset, mongodb-compass

I have set up a replica set with two nodes that hold data. Now I wanted to add an Arbiter. I saw some confusing behavior when administrating the my replica set and would be glad if someone could make sense of it.

I logged on to the replica set with MongoDB Compass and the mongosh interface it provides. My connection string looks like this:

```
mongodb://node1:port,node2:port/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&replicaSet=rsName&readPreference=nearest&authSource=%24external&appname=MongoDB+Compass&ssl=true
```

I wanted to add a Arbiter to my replica set as I only have two nodes in my set so far.

```
use admin
'switched to db admin'
rs.addArb("node3:port")
{
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1659347675, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1659347675, i: 1 })
}
```

So this command ran without a problem. As there was an issue with the Arbiter I wanted to remove it, still in the same session in MongoDB Compass:

```
rs.remove("node3:port")
MongoServerError: New config is rejected :: caused by :: replSetReconfig should only be run on a writable PRIMARY. Current state SECONDARY;
```

I am very confused by this message, I just added the node with the same session and also I specified both servers in the connection string, so I would expect the command to be passed to the primary whichever it is.

I was able to get past this by retrying until the command was accepted.

```
rs.remove("node3:port")
{
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1659347889, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1659347889, i: 1 })
}
```

Can someone explain to me why I got this odd message and also why it works after retrying a couple times?  Also how can I prevent this?